# Есть ли способ парсить страницу с использованием хром расширения?

Tags: python

я начинающий программист, изучаю Python, придумал себе задачу - написать парсер для торговой площадки в Steam. Саму площадку спарсить ничего сложного, но информацию, которую мне нужно получить отображается на странице с использованием расширения для
хрома(рис.1)

[image: Рисунок 1]

Допустим, что я хочу получить числовое значение поля Paint index, но моя программа банально не видит этой информации, потому что я получил ее с помощью расширения, для сверки вот оригинал(рис.2)
[image: Рисунок 2]

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Как мне получить информацию, полученную с помощью расширения?

Comment: selenium вам в помощь

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю что умеет

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.